# How to modify the extra label of the year when using natbib (authoryear mode), and bibtex8

Tags: bibtex, natbib, authoryear

By using the `natbib` package, the extra label of the year (e.g., 2000a, 2000b, 2000c, etc.) can be obtained by `\natexlab` command. I intend to write a macro, but I'm not familiar with the TeX programming language. The purpose is to write a macro for the `\natexlab{<arg?}` command that evaluates the input argument and replaces `a` by `alef`, `b` by `be`, `c` by `pe`, and if anything else other than these letters were specified, print the argument with no changes. I will be glad if you do this for me.

**Update 1:** I made a customized bib style (`.bst` file) by `makebst` based on `natbib` package. My final goal is to replace “alef, be, pe, etc.” by corresponding Persian/Farsi characters; so, I will be grateful that you define a macro named `\natexlab{<arg>}` that does this for me.

**Update 2 (for clarification):** I created a package (`.sty` file) alongside the `.bst` file, and this macro will be defined there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. I may be easier to implement your desired formatting in the bib style file than by hacking the `natbib` style file.

Comment: @Mico I made a customized bib style by `makebst` based on `natbib` package. My final goal is to replace alef, be, pe, etc. by corresponding Persian/Farsi characters; so, I will be grateful that define a macro named `\natexlab{<arg>}` which do this for me, then I implement this to the corresponding `.sty` file.